# Why it's bad that overload a class static method with different arguments

Tags: python, overloading, static-methods

I have Python codes:

```
class A(object):

    @staticmethod
    def print():
        print('A')


class B(A):

    @staticmethod
    def print(val):
        print('B' + str(val))
```

And I want to use them like this:

```
    A.print()
    >>> A
    B.print(1)
    >>> B1
```

But in IDE, I receive warning as following: **Signature of method 'B.print()' does not match signature of the base method in class 'A'**, which means the overloading is not in good practice. Can someone tell me why it's bad? In my scenario, what is the correct way to define the print method in class A and B? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you perhaps mean to make them `classmethod`s instead? Static methods are usually called from instances, and in this case changing the signature _will_ break code that does so.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, this question is duplicated, please see the top